# Multiple fields relationated with one table (CakePHP3)

Tags: associations, cakephp-3.0

I have a table named "communications" and it has two fields: "ethernet_id" and "gprs_id", these two fields are foreign keys to another table named "communication_hosts".

My problem is that when I make the association with:

```
    $this->belongsTo('CommunicationHosts')
         ->setForeignKey('gprs_id')
         ->setProperty('gprs'); //I have the "communications.gprs" in the form

    $this->belongsTo('CommunicationHosts')
         ->setForeignKey('ethernet_id')
         ->setProperty('ethernet');  //I have the "communications.gprs" in the form
```

It only creates the Ethernet object and doesn't create the GPRS object, but it creates a gprs simple array.

Is there any way to do this association in CakePHP3?